# Access Query - Not Like

Tags: ms-access-2010, criteria

I have a Access DB with a customer list that needs to be contacted.  As soon as the person has finished contacting the customer the "Status" column should be updated to "Done" or "Call Back" or "Engaged" Or whatever the status must be.  Then when the query is run it should exclude all the customers that is "Done" in the status column.

Problem is I can not get this query to work and I can not figure out the problem.  I've attached some print screens.  Help will be greatly appreciated.

The table structure:
[image]

Some table data:
[image]

The Query:
[image]

The query result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because of ignoring if status is null, change status in top to nz(status,"")

```
 nz(status,"") not like "*Done*"
```